# SaveAs method in vbscript throws error

Tags: vbscript

Thanks for your help in advance.
I am running a VbScript(code below) to edit a .csv file and save it as another file, however, I keep getting the following error:

> Line: 30 Char: 1 Error: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed Code: 800A03EC

---

```
Dim xlApp, xlWkb, xlSh, SourceFolder, TargetFolder, file
Dim str, strClean
Dim cell

Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

SourceFolder="I:\Documents\Rajarshi_SVN Repositorywc\Global Fund Services - Long Funds\02_Funds STP\02_Funds STP Phase 1\03_Test scripts\04_Test data\CSV - Chk"
TargetFolder="I:\Documents\Rajarshi_SVN Repositorywc\Global Fund Services - Long Funds\02_Funds STP\02_Funds STP Phase 1\03_Test scripts\04_Test data\CSV - New"

xlApp.visible = false

For Each file in fs.GetFolder(SourceFolder).files

 Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file)
 BaseName = fs.getbasename(file) 
 Set xlSh = xlWkb.Worksheets(1)

For Each cell in xlSh.Range("A2:XFD2")

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[\/[0-9a-zA-Z]*\/]*"
        .Global = True
        cell = .Replace(cell, vbNullString)
    End With

Next

FullTargetPath=TargetFolder & "\" & BaseName & ".csv"
xlWkb.SaveAs FullTargetPath, xlCSV, , , , , , 2
xlWkb.Saved = True
xlWkb.Close
Set xlSh = Nothing
Set xlWkb = Nothing

Next

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing

MsgBox "XML Files headers converted successfully"
```

---

I am okay even if I am able to simply save the file.

Comment: Error received is as below:
Line: 30
Char: 1
Error: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed
Code: 800A03EC

Comment: Does the target folder exist? I haven't come across this issue myself yet so I wouldn't know for sure how to solve it, but after a little research I noticed other people faced this if the target folder doesn't exist yet. Also, to make sure you are not messing up the `FullTargetPath`, I would rather use `FullTargetPath=fs.BuildPath(TargetFolder,BaseName & ".csv")`. This avoids excessive backslash characters being added by mistake (not completely related to the question)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The required change was in the line
xlWkb.SaveAs FullTargetPath, xlCSV, , , , , , 2
This should be:
xlWkb.SaveAs FullTargetPath
This is working.

Comment: You can add your own answer to this question and accept it. I'm glad you make it work on your own